# How to response with an mp3 file using Vapor?

Tags: swift, vapor

I can directly return mp3 file with code below, but I cannot seek position (drag the slider) of this mp3 file in
Chrome, for example, mp3 file in this url: http://193.123.246.233/api/songs/file/chengdu.mp3, I don't know whether it's the problem of my network or the code, thanks

```html
func getSongHandler(_ req: Request) throws -> Response {
    guard let songName = req.parameters.get("songName") else {
        return Response(status: .notFound);
    }
    let filePath = workingDirectory + "Resources/Songs/" + songName
    let fileURL = URL(fileURLWithPath: filePath)
    let data = try Data(contentsOf: fileURL)
    var headers = HTTPHeaders()
    headers.add(name: .contentType, value: "audio/mpeg")
    return Response(headers: headers, body: .init(data: data))
}
```

Comment: Do you use `nginx` in front of Vapor? Anyway take a look at FileMiddleware sourcecode, there you will see hot to stream the file, you could try it.

Comment: @imike I haven't use nginx in front of Vapor, should I use it? And I will take a look at FileMiddleware and use it. thx

Comment: I think I have solved this issue by looking at how FileMiddleWare stream the file, the mp3 url now work as expected, thx @imike

Comment: That's cool, congrats! Also if you use `FileMiddleware` in production be careful cause it is trying to read files from disk on every request, so performance will be poor. It is solvable either by rewriting it and read from disk only if url contains known extension like .png, .css, etc. just by checking if url.lastPathComponent has suffix. Or the best option for serving static files is to use nginx in front of vapor, cause nginx doing it efficiently, it was well optimized for that.